# Proposition $1.24(c)$ of Rudin's RCA is also true when $c =\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I need to show that Proposition $1.24(c)$ of Rudin's RCA is also true when $c =\infty$.

> Proposition $1.24(c)$: $\mu$ is a positive measure, $f\ge 0$, $0\le c < \infty$, then
> $$\int_E cf\ d\mu = c\int_E f\ d\mu$$

*My work:*
Suppose $\int_E f\ d\mu = 0$. Then, $f = 0$ a.e. on $E$, implying $cf = 0$ a.e. on $E$. The result follows. On the other hand, suppose $\int_E f\ d\mu > 0$. The RHS is $c\int_E f\ d\mu = \infty$. What about the LHS?

**Edit:** I also came across this solution which I can use some help with -

> [image]

When $\int_X f\ d\mu > 0$, what guarantees the existence of an $\epsilon > 0$ and a measurable set $E$ such that $\mu(E) > 0$ and $x\in E\implies f(x) > \epsilon$? I understand the rest of the proof.

Comment: As I recall, Rudin adopts the convention that $0\cdot\infty =0$, right?

Comment: That's correct. @MPW

Comment: There are two cases to consider: $f-0$ almost surely in $E$, in which case $c\cdot f=0$ (by a well established oncvension) ; and the case in which $\mu(f>0)>0$. In the former you get $0=\int \infty\cdot0=\infty \int 0$; in the later you get $\infty=\infty\int f=\int \infty f=\int_{\{f>0\}}\infty f$.

Comment: I have already handled the first case, I believe. Need help with the other one @OliverDiaz

Comment: @OliverDiaz What do you do after $\int_{\{f > 0\}} f$? How do you justify $\infty \int f = \int \infty f$? Beyond that, I think it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f\geq0$ and measurable.

- Suppose $\mu(\{f>0\})>0$. Then $\int f\,d\mu>0$ and so $\infty\cdot\int f\,d\mu=\infty$. On the other hand, $\infty\cdot f=\infty\mathbb{1}_{\{f>0\}}$, hence $\int \infty\cdot f\,d\mu=\int_{\{f>0\}}\infty\,d\mu=\infty$.
- Suppose $\mu(\{f>0\})=0$. Then $\int f\,d\mu=0$ and by convention $\infty\cdot\int f=0$. Also, as $\infty\cdot f=\infty\mathbb{1}_{\{f>0\}}$, $\int \infty\cdot f\,d\mu=\infty\cdot \mu(\{f>0\})=\infty\cdot0=0$.

---

**Edit:** to show that if $f\geq0$, $\mu(A)>0$ and $\int_A f=0$ then $f=0$ almost surely on $A$:
$$\mu(x\in A:f(x)>\tfrac1n)\leq n\int_{A\cap\{f>\tfrac1n\}}f\leq n\int_Af=0$$
As $A\cap\{f>\tfrac1n\}\nearrow A\cap\{f>0\}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $\mu(\{x\in A: f(x)>\tfrac1n\})=0$.

- From this, it follows that if $f\geq0$, and $\mu(x\in A:f(x)>0)>0$, then $\int_Af>0$.

Comment: I just added more details. Let me now if this make thins clearer

Comment: Amazing, it makes sense now! Just one quick question - in the step where you've applied Chebyshev's inequality, won't the integral be over $A \cap \left\{f \ge \frac1n \right\}$, i.e. with equality?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: You can also use $\geq$ instead of $>$. I have a preference  to consider sets $(a,b]$ so that distributions $F(x)=\mu(\infty,x])$ are right continuous with left limits.